# list all metrics which crossed threshold values on checks in sensu

Tags: graphite, sensu

I have metrics going into graphite server from sensu.

I need to list all the particular pattern of metrics which crossed the threshold value ,set by me using Graphite functions.

As of now i am using "ruby check-graphite-data.rb -s xx.xx.xx.xx:8080 -t 'averageAbove(internal.sensuclient.*.diskusage.root.boot.used_percentage,5)' -w 12 -c 13",when it executed ,getting only one output but i need more than one output,which has value greater than 5.

I had installed sensu-Client on graphite server and executing the checks.

Please suggest me where i am getting wrong and the correct function to be used to get all metrices ,so i can send alerts .

Thanks in advance

Comment: Can't you just get all `internal.sensuclient.*.diskusage.root.boot.used_percentage` and do the comparation in the Ruby code? Check the Graphite URL interface.

Comment: Thanks .
as i am new to graphite-sensu. please elaborate the solution